# Converting string into a type supported by KNeighborsClassifier in Python

Tags: python, sockets, knn

I have converted an object of KNeighborsClassifier into a string to send it from client to server. I found it as an incompatable datatype when I use the received data at the server side.

Program at the client side

```
knn=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
clf = knn.fit(X_train_tfidf, twenty_train.target)
sock.sendall(str(clf))
```

Here the type of clf is KNeighborsClassifier which is converted into a string. Is there any way to convert the string back to KNeighborsClassifier type.
Thanks in advance

Comment: No. Why do you assume that the result of `str` on a `KNeighborsClassifier` would be able to be converted back to the original object? This isn't true in general.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga **Actually we need to send `clf` to sever. But without converting we are not able to send it as we need a string or character buffer object for sending. Is there any way to send it without converting it into string?**

Comment: send a pickle. Or serialize it some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

```
import pickle
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
clf.fit(X_train_tfidf, twenty_train.target)
sock.sendall(pickle.dumps(clf))

# On the other side of the socket
import pickle
clf = pickle.loads(socket_input)
```

Comment: **We are not able to send the serialized data. The error is:** `sock.sendall(pickle.dumps(clf))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`

Comment: That's a problem with the socket, not with the persistence of the model. Can you provide more details?

Comment: **I implemented the client server interaction by referring [https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html]. I can serialize the data but can't send it. It is showing the above mentioned error**

Comment: **My  problem  with more details is expressed here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015914/sending-serialized-data-from-client-to-server-in-python]. Please help me. My project is entirely depending on this.**